# Getting blank pdf from ajax call returning HttpResponseMessage in webapp

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am returning HttpResponseMessage from web api and use this in ajax call but getting blank pdf.

my ajax call is

```
function downloadPDF()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(UserData),
            url: rootUrl + "api/WebAPI/Export",
            //dataType: "native",
            contentType: "application/json",
            //responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            //contentType: "application/pdf",

            headers: headers,
            success: function (data) {
                //document.write(data);
                alert(data.size);
                var blob = new Blob([data]);
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "Dossier_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
                link.click();
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think setting the `Response.Content` as your pdf stream and  `Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");` in the web api should automatically download the pdf as part of this ajax call success.

Comment: it is already there. res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

Comment: are you setting the pdf stream to `res.Content`?

Comment: Yes, res.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes);

Answer (score 4):

Convert your HttpResponseMessage(which should be Base64String) to Array Buffer using this function :

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

And then call this function after converting to Array Buffer :

```
function saveByteArray(pdfName, byte) {
    var blob = new Blob([byte], { type: "application/pdf" });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = pdfName + ".pdf";
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
};
```

So your whole ajax call will look like this  :

```
function downloadPDF()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(UserData),
                url: rootUrl + "api/WebAPI/Export",
                //dataType: "native",
                contentType: "application/json",
                //responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                //contentType: "application/pdf",

                headers: headers,
                success: function (data) {
                    //document.write(data);
                    alert(data.size);
                var bytes = base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
                saveByteArray("Dossier_" + new Date(), bytes);

                }
        }
```